# Which of these two regression models should I choose?

Tags: regression, model-selection

I have two regression models with the following results. How can I decide upon on selecting the better regression model. Can you please help me in getting the perfect approach to start off for these kind of analysis.

```
Model 1: Call:
lm(formula = salary ~ yrs.since.phd, data = Salaries)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-84171 -19432  -2858  16086 102383 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    91718.7     2765.8  33.162   <2e-16 ***
yrs.since.phd    985.3      107.4   9.177   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 27530 on 395 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1758,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1737 
F-statistic: 84.23 on 1 and 395 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Model 2: Call:
lm(formula = salary ~ yrs.service, data = Salaries)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-81933 -20511  -3776  16417 101947 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  99974.7     2416.6   41.37  < 2e-16 ***
yrs.service    779.6      110.4    7.06 7.53e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 28580 on 395 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1121,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1098 
F-statistic: 49.85 on 1 and 395 DF,  p-value: 7.529e-12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods to see which model fits the data better.

1. Look at whether the coefficients for your model are significant. Are the p-values less than a pre-defined significance level (i.e. 5%). If the p-values for the coefficients are less than 5% one can say they are significant. Firstly check that both your models have coefficients that are significant, especially the slope coefficient. A significant slope coefficient indicates that there may be a linear relationship between your dependent variable (Y) and independent variable (X). Both your models have coefficients that are significant.
2. Compare the $R^2$ values of the two models. This is the coefficient of determination of your fitted model. This is the amount of variation that is explained in your dependent variable (Y) by the variation in your independent variable (X). In your case Model 1 has an $R^2=17.58\%$ which is larger than the      $R^2=11.21\%$ in Model 2. One says the Model with a larger $R^2$ value is better.
3. You can also compare the Residual Standard Error of the two models (given that you have used the same dependent variable). A lower Residual Standard Error is better. So once again you would select Model 1 over Model 2 as it has a lower Residual Standard Error.

Hope this helps :)